# How anti-virus on the host machine affects performance of virtual machines?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, performance, anti-virus

I'm diagnosing [some issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545203/what-can-cause-slow-run-at-debug-mode) with Oracle virtual box where virtual machine sometimes perform terribly slow (much slower then notebook with worse configuration):

Notebook

- i7 (2 cores with HT = 4 logical CPUs), 4GB RAM, 5400 rpm disk, Win 7 64bit

Virtual machine (Oracle Virtual Box)

- Host: i7 (4 cores with HT = 8 logical CPUs, 12 GB RAM, system runs from SSD, virtual machine from 7200 rpm disk, Win 7 64bit)
- Virtual machine: 4 cores assigned, 8 GB RAM assigned, Win 2008 R2 Enterprise (64 bit)
- Virtual machine uses bridge to separate network interface (machine has two)
- VPN for network communication
- No other virtual machine runs on the host
- Host has installed ESET Smart Security

All SW is updated with last version.

My question is if anti-virus on the host machine can somehow affect performance of the virtual machine and if so how can I turn it off without turning the anti-virus itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to exclude the VirtualBox disk files (.VDI or .VMDK) individually from your anti-virus product (you don't tell us which one you've got).  That will stop on-access scanning from getting in the way of writes to those files.  Whether or not it is or will impact performance is hard to say.

However, there could be plenty of other reasons for your VM running slowly outside of just AV, and you'll need to do more profiling before you can say for certain what it is.

Comment: I mentioned I'm using ESET Smart Security. It contains ESET NOD32 antivirus.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that comment.  Advice stays the same - exclude those file types.